# Calculating rows that match a month in the header

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to calculate the monthly totals for fruit that I record sales of weekly.

I have a table that records the above data.

I would like another table that calculates the SUM values for each month for that fruit. Because every month has a potentially different number of weeks, I need a formula to essentially cycle through the weeks for the particular fruit I'm interested in and SUM the values for that month dynamically.

I've tried a bunch of different things, like:

```
=IF(A3:A5="Banana", SUM(INDEX(C2:J2,,MATCH("January",C3:F3))))
```

...in the hopes that I could somehow:

1. Search for a fruit in a table
2. If found, run through the weeks and
   calculate monthly values

[Spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ul8xIsoolCgI7Nn2thr2vFnajJ-P0ZlrGIl3nXx-GSU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B9 try this formula

```
=sum(filter(filter($C$3:$5, month($C$2:$2)=column()-1), $A$3:$A$5=$A9))
```

Fill down and to the right as far as needed.

Comment: That's the one. Thanks :)